# Check the jumbled words

Tags: code-golf

This is an easy one.

[Anagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anagram) are words which have the same characters but in different order. All you have to do is to figure out if two strings are anagram or not.

Rules:

- Take two strings as a function argument, command-line argument or from standard input.
- Write a function or program which returns truthy value if strings are anagram, falsy value otherwise
- Anagrams may have different number of spaces () characters in them.
- Anagrams are case insensitive matches.
- Anagrams can only have printable ASCII characters for this code-golf.

For example(taken from the Wikipedia page itself): `Doctor Who` is an anagram of `Torchwood` . Note missing space and lack of capital D and W in `Torchwood`

This is code-golf so minimum bytes code win!

Happy golfing.

Comment: Done - Edited to clarify

Comment: If that is considered as standard input (STDIN) then yes.

Comment: printable ascii or alphanumeric? what about ,:;...?

Comment: @MartinBüttner No objection against ARGV from my side. Feel free to edit the question to point it out in clear words as I might not be able to make it clear.

Comment: @edc65 Well, these are just words, not sentences, so ideally those characters should not appear. But if they do, they are to be considered. Same for numbers

Comment: It's an easy one, but attracts an unusual number of wrong answers ...

Comment: The preprocessing required to make this the same as the existing anagram is to remove spaces and lower-case, which is a pretty trivial transformation.

Comment: Anagram Code Golf! did not show up in suggestions while I was creating this one. Weird.

Comment: Not exactly the same, and not all the answers of the old question are valid for this question `(No special characters, only A-Z)`

Comment: @PeterTaylor The rules of the other one are completely opposite of my rules, thus the transformations are not trivial when you think from [tag:code-golf] point of view

Comment: @edc65, "duplicate" doesn't mean "identical" on this site. It also covers simple transformations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### CJam, <s>15</s> 11 bytes

Just thought I'd practice CJam a bit more. This is basically the same as my Ruby answer (or most answers):

```
ea{S-el$}/=
```

Quick explanation

```
ea          "Push command line arguments";
ea{     }/  "For each element in that array";
ea{S-   }/  "Push a space character onto the stack and remove spaces from string";
ea{S-el }/  "Convert string to lower case";
ea{S-el$}/  "Sort the characters in the string";
ea{S-el$}/= "Check for equality";
```

Prints `1` for anagrams and `0` otherwise.

Comment: 1. Brackets can be unmatched in CJam, so you don't need the `[` in `[ll]`. `ea` would be even shorter; it pushes all command-line arguments as an array. Doesn't work with the online interpreter though... 2. `S` is initialized to `" "`, so you can use it instead of `' `. 3. You can replace `%~` with `/`.

Answer (score 4):

## Java, <strike>146</strike> <strike>131</strike> <strike>144</strike> <strike>134</strike> <strike>131</strike> 128

Not a very exciting answer. Returns true for anagrams, false for others. Actually works now. Cheapass abuse of generics in class declaration.

```
boolean b(T a,T b){return c(a).equals(c(b));}T c(T a){char[]c=a.toLowerCase().toCharArray();sort(c);return(T)valueOf(c).trim();}
```

Ungolfed:

```
boolean b(T a,T b) {
    return c(a).equals(c(b));
}

T c(T a) {
    char[] c = a.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    sort(c);
    return (T) valueOf(c).trim();
}
```

Comment: mmm... cat and faq?

Comment: Two different strings can have the same ASCII sum. Take, for e.g., the strings `"bb"(98 + 98)` and `"ac"(97 + 99)`.

Comment: Is `valueOf` a static import?

Comment: yeah, same with sort

Answer (score 3):

### Ruby, <s>65</s> <s>60</s> <s>58</s> <s>57</s> <s>51</s> <s>48</s> 46 bytes

```
s,t=$*.map{|u|u.upcase.scan(/\S/).sort};p s==t
```

<s>**Edit:** Switched to STDIN to save a few bytes.</s>

**Edit:** Switched to ARGV to save three more bytes.

Quite long for such a simple problem, hmmmm.

- For each string:

  - Turn to upper case (to make it case in-sensitive).
  - Split into non-whitespace characters.
  - Sort (by character code).
- Then check that the results are equal.

Comment: Wow everything i would like to have in C# - nice one +1

Answer (score 3):

## Rebol   <s>44</s>   40

(Rebol 2)

Define a function `m` which takes two values `a` and `b`. `Sort` each string, `trim` the whitespace and use `=` to check if the strings are the same.

```
m: func[a b][(trim sort a)= trim sort b]
```

<s>m: func[a b][equal? trim sort a trim sort b]</s>

Example

```
>> m: func[a b][(trim sort a)= trim sort b] 
>> m "Doctor Who" "Torchwood"             
== true
```

It is useful handy that `sort` is case insensitive by default. Note: This function does have side effects if you use this code elsewhere as `sort` modifies a and b directly.

(`sort` should work in Rebol 3 but doesn't as there is a known bug)

Comment: Yes ... :( <backs slowly away from keyboard and slaps forehead>

Comment: That should work. Just a few chars longer

Comment: Wait, I don't understand. Just because `sort` sorts case insensitively, how does that make `equal?` work on strings of different cases?

Comment: Oh `equal?` itself is case insensitive, too. That's... handy.

Comment: and `same? "ABC" "abc"` is `false` :) Also has the shorthand `"ABC" == "abc"` - double equal signs means really equal!

Comment: @MARTINBÜTTNER The need to use `==` instead of `=` to get case sensitive comparison, and instruct the primitives to use it with a refinement (e.g. SORT/CASE instead of SORT) is a choice that leads to grumbling from some in the Rebol and Red community.  From a hardware point of view, it's kind of like "a" is "A" - handling uppercase specially being the exception and not the rule.  I've theorized that if keyboards had 52 letters Rebol would be case-sensitive by default, and if you had to push shift to get a `[` and didn't for a `{` it would use curly braces for code blocks...

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6) 68 <s>99</s>

Generate a key for each word and compare them. If only JS had some shorter ucase method...

```
A=(a,b,k=s=>[...s.toUpperCase()].sort().join('').trim())=>k(a)==k(b)
```

Comment: You always bring in unique techniques to the table :)

Comment: @Optimizer you're kind, but nothing new here, this is really a standard way to handle anagrams

Comment: No, I was talking about the declare a second method in the third argument and use it to save space trick.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3 -- <s>73</s> 67 bytes

---

Code:

```
f=lambda:sorted(i for i in input().upper()if" "!=i);print(f()==f())
```

As usual, nice looking, but not very short. Typical python...

Comment: Does `a#b` count as an word? Fixed.

Comment: The challenge asks for printable ASCII, so all characters except spaces should be treated as "letters" for the purposes of the challenge.

Answer (score 2):

## Cobra - 130

```
do(a='',b='')
    print (f=Func<of String,String>(do(s='')=s.toLower.toCharArray.toList.sorted.join('').trim)).invoke(a)==f.invoke(b)
```

Comment: Sorted first, then tolower: couldn't this create problems?

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6) 82

Returns true if the two strings are anagrams, otherwise returns false or throws an exception

```
e=(a,b)=>(a.replace(/\S/g,c=>b=b.replace(b.match(RegExp(c,'i'))[0],'')),!b.trim())
```

Comment: "or throws an exception" violates the rules, though. That's not a falsy value as required.

Comment: Throwing makes this an invalid entry :(

Answer (score 1):

## Perl - 84

Always need Perl in these...

```
sub c{map{s/\s//}@a=@_;(join'',sort split//,lc$a[0])eq join'',sort split//,lc$a[1]}
```

Wanted to be able to modify @_ directly but perl wont allow that

Comment: How should this be called? It doesn't seem to return a result.

Comment: It returns a 1 or a 0 --->    print c('Doctor Who','Torchwood') ? 'Yes' : 'No';

Answer (score 1):

## Bash+coreutils, 62 bytes

```
s()(tr -d '     '<<<"${@^^}"|fold -1|sort)
cmp <(s $1) <(s $2)
```

Takes arguments from the command line.  Return code 0 for TRUE and 1 for FALSE.  Also something like `/dev/fd/63 /dev/fd/62 differ: byte 1, line 1` is output in the FALSE case.

#### Output:

```
$ ./anagram.sh "Doctor Who" Torchwood; echo $?
0
$ ./anagram.sh "Doctor Watson" Torchwood; echo $?
/dev/fd/63 /dev/fd/62 differ: byte 1, line 1
1
$
```

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure : 84 chars

Golfed:

```
(defn g[s](sort(remove #(= \  %)(seq(.toLowerCase s)))))
(defn f[a b](=(g a)(g b)))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(defn g[s] (sort (remove #(= \  %) (seq (.toLowerCase s)))))
(defn f[a b] (= (g a) (g b)) )
```

Driver program with execution:

```
(def a "Doctor   Who")
(def b "Torch woo d")
(println (f a b))

bash$ java -jar clojure-1.6.0.jar anagram.clj 
true
```

Answer (score 0):

### Groovy : <strike>96</strike> 77 chars

Golfed:

```
g={it.findAll{it!=" "}.collect{it.toLowerCase()}.sort()}
f={a,b->g(a)==g(b)}
```

Ungolfed:

```
g = { it.findAll{ it!=" " }.collect{ it.toLowerCase() }.sort() }
f = { a,b -> g(a)==g(b) }
```

Example main program and execution:

```
a="Doctor Who x x"
b="Tor chwoo dxx"
println f(a,b)

$ groovy Anagram.groovy
$ true
```